# Automatic IPA uploading with Jenkins and altool fails with 'Transporter not found' error

Tags: ios, iphone, jenkins, continuous-integration, application-loader

I'm using Jenkins and `altool` to validate an iOS package and upload it to my iTunes account automatically. While the validation works fine and I receive no error, the uploading doesn't work.

> '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool'
>   --upload-app -f my_application.ipa -u **** -p '****'

And as a result I'm getting the following error:

> altool[35164:1584273] Error: Exception while launching
>   iTunesTransporter: Transporter not found at path:
>   /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter.  You should reinstall the
>   application. altool[35164:1584271] Error: Errors uploading

If I take the same package and try to upload it using `Application Loader` everything works fine.

Comment: I vaguely recall getting this error after upgrading Xcode at some point. You might try recreating the `/usr/local/itms` symlink to point to the proper subdirectory of Xcode.app. e.g. something like this for Xcode 7.1: ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms /usr/local/itms

Comment: that helped! Please reply with an answer to mark it as a solution

Comment: It's a bug in `altool` that still exists in Application Loader 3.4 which is bundled with Xcode 7.2.  Be sure to file a bug report so it gets fixed.

Comment: How are you automating this with Jenkins, @AlexeyStrakh ? Is there a plugin for that, or are you using a "shell" step ? Does a "password" have to be specified "as-is" or is it possible to use credentials provider ? Can you provide an example ? Thanks !!

Comment: shell exec, just it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try recreating the `/usr/local/itms` symlink to point to the proper subdirectory of Xcode.app. e.g.something like this for Xcode 7.1:

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms /usr/local/itms
```

This may be necessary after Xcode gets upgraded.